# Configuring search query component on web server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search, query, sharepoint-search

We have three tier architecture in SharePoint 2013 (2 Web, 2 App, DB).

We are configuring search as Web server (for Query component) and App server (for other components).

We are **facing issue while activating the search topology** on Web server for query component, but it is working fine if configuring query on App servers.

Network Admin team is saying it is a **port opening issue**.

Which are the ports needed for query components configuration on web servers?

Comment: On what server is the Index Component situated?

Comment: Index is on App servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following URLs provide information on the required ports for firewalls:

Plan security hardening for SharePoint 2013: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262849.aspx

SharePoint 2013 Ports, Proxies and Protocols: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uksharepoint/2013/01/21/sharepoint-2013-ports-proxies-and-protocols-an-overview-of-farm-communications/

Work your way through these to get an exhaustive list of the required firewall ports.

Comment: Ports given in first link is already open. Thanks for second link. It is also giving same ports.

Comment: Thanks. Because of the approval process delay to open ports we configured query component on app servers and tested. Working fine from all four servers.